# OSError: meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf is not a local folder

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, llama

I'm trying to replied the code from this [Hugging Face blog](https://huggingface.co/blog/llama2). At first I installed the transformers and created a token to login to hugging face hub:

```
pip install transformers
huggingface-cli login
```

After that it is said to use `use_auth_token=True` when you have set a token. Unfortunately after running the code I get an error:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers
import torch

model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model, use_auth_token=True)
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
)

sequences = pipeline(
    'I liked "Breaking Bad" and "Band of Brothers". Do you have any recommendations of other shows I might like?\n',
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=10,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    max_length=200,
)
for seq in sequences:
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
```

Error:

```
OSError: meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf is not a local folder and is not a valid model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
If this is a private repository, make sure to pass a token having permission to this repo with `use_auth_token` or log in with `huggingface-cli login` and pass `use_auth_token=True`.
```

It says that the model cannot be found, but you can find it in the list of models on hugging face [here](https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf).

This is the version of the `transformers` package I'm using:

```
> pip show transformers

Name: transformers
Version: 4.33.0.dev0
Summary: State-of-the-art Machine Learning for JAX, PyTorch and TensorFlow
Home-page: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
Author: The Hugging Face team (past and future) with the help of all our contributors (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/graphs/contributors)
Author-email: transformers@huggingface.co
License: Apache 2.0 License
Location: /Users/quinten/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: filelock, huggingface-hub, numpy, packaging, pyyaml, regex, requests, safetensors, tokenizers, tqdm
Required-by: spacy-transformers
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: You did all of the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama/issues/374#issuecomment-1643228958), right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs):
```

the pretrained_model_name_or_path may the model repo or the model path

in your case the model repo is "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf" which is right.

according to https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf/tree/main

you should apply a license of the model.