# ValueError: Tokenizer class LlamaTokenizer does not exist or is not currently imported

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, llama

I am trying to run the code from this [Hugging Face blog](https://huggingface.co/blog/llama2). At first, I had no access to the model so this error: [OSError: meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf is not a local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77006745/oserror-meta-llama-llama-2-7b-chat-hf-is-not-a-local-folder), is now solved and I created an acces token from Hugging Face which works. Now I'm facing a different error when running the following code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers
import torch

model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model, use_auth_token=True)
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
)

sequences = pipeline(
    'I liked "Breaking Bad" and "Band of Brothers". Do you have any recommendations of other shows I might like?\n',
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=10,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    max_length=200,
)
for seq in sequences:
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Tokenizer class LlamaTokenizer does not exist or is not currently imported.
```

The error is not the same as this error: [ImportError: cannot import name 'LLaMATokenizer' from 'transformers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75907910/importerror-cannot-import-name-llamatokenizer-from-transformers), because now it is a valuerror. To make sure I use the right version I run this code:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```

After that I checked this issue [ValueError: Tokenizer class LLaMATokenizer does not exist or is not currently imported. #22222](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/22222)
. This suggests:

> Change the LLaMATokenizer in tokenizer_config.json into lowercase
> LlamaTokenizer and it works like a charm.

So, I checked the files if it is using `LLamaTokenizer` instead of `LlamaTokenizer` like for example here (This is the class in the file):

```
class LlamaTokenizer(PreTrainedTokenizer):
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error?

Comment: If your tokenizers version is 0.13.2 or lower, I recommend upgrading it to 0.13.3. This solves my problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have followed the guide here: https://huggingface.co/blog/llama2 but it doesn't mention anything about tokenizers. News? @AbuShoeb how did you updated? Could you say more about the command/library?

Answer (score 9):

Just run the following command and you should be good.
It will upgrade your `transformers` library and automatically pull the latest `tokenizers` for you

`pip install --upgrade transformers`

Comment: This is also useful for the new gemma tokenizer and model that Google just released

Comment: I also faced the same issue with NllbTokenizer, and this helped. If HuggingFace could mention in docs the version of transformers required for a given model or tokenizer, that would be very helpful.